# Can alleles have cyclic dominance?

Tags: genetics, allele

Do the relationships between alleles always form a hierarchy? Ignoring partial and codominance, can alleles have a cyclic relationship? For example, is there anything that exists analogous to the following 3 fictional alleles:

Rock -> Scissors -> Paper -> Rock

If so, it's easy to see what would happen in a diploid relationship and which phenotype would be expressed. But what would happen in a triploid organism? Would nothing be expressed because each allele was dominated by another?

Comment: Have you thought about what dominance is caused by?

Comment: I understand situations like a pigment being produced or not being produced. But what I'm asking abouot if any boundary conditions exist that are outside the norm. Specifically, modes of inheritance that have non-binary causes.